# Cordova pushnotification android

Tags: android, cordova, push

I want to implemnet Android Push Notifications.
I found this Plugin but I dont't know how to install/use it:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

DO I JUST HAVE TO INSTALL IT (and then configure it)

or is there another plugin (or file) needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should visit :
http://console.developers.google.com/

and get sender and api key .

more info about 
https://usergrid.apache.org/docs/push-notifications/tutorial.html

then you should add some code as documented in plugin github document in device ready to submit device to google service . 
When the plugin fired it responses a device id , you should use it later to recognize devices to send the message. 
you can use [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) for .net platform to handle this.

- I recommend to use version 2.4 of pushplugin instead of latest version.
  it avoids some unclear errors like :

  Oh oh !